# Keycloak javascript adapter how to get token api call values back into code

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I am using the Keycloak javascript adapter in my react app.

```
const keycloak = Keycloak({
  url: keyCloakConfig.url,
  realm: keyCloakConfig.realm,
  clientId: keyCloakConfig.clientId
});

keycloak.init({
  onLoad: 'login-required',
  promiseType: 'native'
});
console.log('keycloak', keycloak.token);
```

I set the Access Type to Public in Client settings in Keyclaok admin. In the Network tab in chrome debug console, I could see a call happening to http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/realm-name/protocol/openid-connect/token and the response is like below.

[image]

But, I could get these values back into the code. When I console keycloak.token the value is undefined.

Please guide me on how to proceed.

Comment: Did you try to log keycloak.access_token. Because as I can see the property name is access_token

Comment: No it didnt work. access_token is undefined.

Comment: As per the documentation after init, token should be available on keycloak.token https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keycloak.init() method returns a promise:

```
    keycloak.init({
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        promiseType: 'native'
    }).then(auth => {
        if(auth) {
        console.log("token", keycloak.token);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The application is running at 3000 port and keycloak at 8080. When I am placing your code I am getting cors error. How can I pass through?

Comment: you can use [nginx reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy) to run keycloak and your application on same domain, configuration for keycloak and your application should look like [this](https://github.com/namy16/nginx-keycloak/blob/master/nginx.conf).

Comment: I am not sure where to do this. Can you guide me here?

Comment: Yes it gives you the token, but not in right format. keycloak.tokenParsed returns only parsed jwt that that does not have that information that you need.

Answer (score 3):

I could not find any possibility to get the token info in that format, but by default, when you take your tokenParsed like:

```
keycloak.init({
    onLoad: 'login-required',
    promiseType: 'native'
}).then(auth => {
    if(auth) {
    console.log("token", keycloak.tokenParsed);
    }
});
```

**You can get info that you need from the parsed token**. Here the token expire time named "exp".The token refreshed time named "iat" and etc. Whole information that you need is here, but names of fields are really stupid.
PS. If you want to format "exp" field to the regular date you can do

```
const date = new Date(keycloak.tokenParsed.exp * 1000)
```

[image]